# Removing all characters before last alpha character

Tags: php, regex

I have a mixed string such as:

```
Job number  45752 Subtotal price $937.50 
Job number  7852 Subtotal amount $637.50 
Job number  42 Subtotal test $427.50 
Job number  47592 Subtotal sample $976.50
```

How do I detect the last alphabet character like the 1st sample 'e' on price, and get its position and then remove all other characters in front?

I know `strpos` can be used to find the last character

```
strpos(string,find,start)
```

But how to make it to track any alphabet instead of a fixed one? I am guessing regex might help but just no idea how to put it in. Please help.

Comment: do you want to only get $937.50 part of the string

Comment: yup. same case for all the samples, just need the $ amount part in the end. but amount some times may be in thousands or tens as well

Comment: What exactly is the expected output

Comment: use this `preg_replace('/.*(\$[\d.]+).*/iU', '$1', $text)`

Comment: Why not explode for space and use the last element which is the price

Comment: preg_replace('/.*(\$[\d.]+).*/iU', '$1', $text) --> this works, thanks!!

Comment: @dan your regex won't satisfy the condition you gave in the question description.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083

Comment: @AvinashRaj *simple* is matter of your own knowledge. Nevertheless, this question is good. The OP provided detailled examples and the approach he found so far. Being "simple" is no cause for a bad question imho.

Comment: Could you just search for the dollar sign instead?

Comment: As others have said, why not just match for the price at the end of the string. "/(\$[\d.]+)$/"

Answer (score 6):

With regex [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function, using [flags](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `i` caseless and `m` multi-line mode:
To replace from `^` line start to the last alpha with optional spaces, put a [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) before `[a-z]`

```
$str = preg_replace('/^.*[a-z]\h*/im', "", $str);
```

`\h*` matches any amount of horizontal space. See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oX2hG1/1), [eval.in](https://eval.in/406473), [regex quickstart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Without start anchor I think there is a bit more steps/backtracking.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can helps:

```
/.* ([^a-z]+)$/igm
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/xP4hB1/1)
or

```
/([^a-z]+)$/igm
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/xP4hB1/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

`strstr()` to do this.

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
echo $domain;
```

// prints @example.com

Ref:http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: thanks, problem is the last character is not fixed. so it won't work

Comment: you set first and last character?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to extract the dollar amount. you can do this alternatively. You can use [strrchr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php):

```
strrchr ( $string, '$' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Job number 45752 Subtotal price $937.50";
$regex = "/.*([a-z])[^a-z]+$/i";
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

echo $matches[1][1];
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Job number 45752 Subtotal price $937.50
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => 30
        )

)
```

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/xP4hB1/3

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str ="Job number  3333 Subtotal price $937.50 ";
$cost = substr($str, strpos($str, "$") + 1);    
echo '$'.$cost;
```

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend string functions instead of regex**, since they're a lot faster. 
I assume you want the price, just find the last space, and continue from there:

```
$lastSpace = strros($string, ' ')+1; // find the last space
echo substr($string, $lastSpace);
```

---

If you have a fixed curr:ency (e.g.: `$`), you can do the same thing for the currency character

```
$lastChar = strros($string, '$')+1; // find the last matching char
echo substr($string, $lastChar );
```

Removing the `$` would give you the price with sign, +1 without. Whichever your prefer.

Answer (score 0):

While several answers have been given already, I want to point out something that none of them touches, [I18N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization). What if the prices are given in different currencies?

```
Job number  45752 Subtotal price CHF937.50 
Job number  7852 Subtotal amount NOK637.50 
Job number  42 Subtotal test SEK427.50 
Job number  47592 Subtotal sample DKK976.50
```

Assuming that a currency is denoted with a special non-alphabetic symbol is false for the vast majority of the world's currencies. By searching for the last space character like [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31653679/23118) suggest you will not limit the code to be dollar currency only.

---

Although the example as given above is not a typical and good one because usually there would be a space between the currency code and the amount when using [currency codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217). And also assuming that the amount comes after the currency indicator is false for many locales, so there is 
more into proper i18n-handling than this, but at least start by not writing code that is limited to handle dollars only.